# Why cold on the back hurts more than cold in the front?

Tags: blood-tests, blood-pressure, back, blood-circulation, oil-of-skin

I'd rather have appended this to the health group, but I guess the biology se was better for this.

The question is, why is it that the cold, on the back, hurts, whereas the cold on the front, arms, and especially the head, does not.

Is it that the skin on the back id's thicker and tighter?

Why does this condition lessen with cold weather, which makes the blood, also, feel cleaner?

At a minimum tell me if this is due to fat cell thickness or sensor density (and I am sure it must be the latter if these were the only two variables), and tell me what the neck the blood system does there. How are the heat sensors connected to the blood, heat, and circulation. I want to live.

What is it?